# How to prove that the space of finitely nonzero sequences of rational numbers is countable?

Tags: sequences-and-series

I was attempting to prove that $l^p$ is separable and concluded that since $c_{00}$ is dense in $l^p$ it should be easier to prove that $c_{00}$ is separable.
Now since "$c_{00}$ with rational coefficients" is dense in $c_{00}$ (w.r.t the $l^p$-norm) it seems like a good candidate to prove the separability of $l^p$.
I have tried to prove myself that it is countable, but I have failed so far (though google tells me I am right, it doesn't tell me why...)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The members of $c_{00}$ with rational coefficients whose every coefficient at rank $n$ and later on is $0$ are in bijection with $\mathbb Q^n$, which is countable. The union over $n$ of these is $c_{00}$, hence $c_{00}$ is indeed countable.

Comment: Thanks! Things can be so simple... :)